# Angular httpClientModule

Tags: angular

I can´t handle res in array form by httpClientModule.
The Api is created by NodeJS. A easy try looks like that:

> res.send( [ { message: 'lego api!' } , { name: 'lucy' } ] );

The response works when i test it by my browser.
No i wants to use the same url in Angular. For I imported the httpClientModule in app.module. The app component looks like that:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.list());
  }
  list(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api').map(data => data.message);
  }
```

In console i only get the informations of the observable:

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator
:
MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}

source
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

_isScalar
:
false

**proto**
:
Object

I dont get what i´m doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to your Observable.

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method.

[docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe)

Comment: i can´t believe that i missed the subscribe. Anyway thanks a lot :)